# Summing dataframe between dates that are located in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

say I have two pandas dataframe df1 and df2 as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                    'Date1':['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'], 
                    'Date2':['2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05']})
df1.loc[:, ['Date1', 'Date2']] = df1.loc[:, ['Date1', 'Date2']].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05'],
                    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'C': [11,12,13,14,15]})
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
```

Is there an efficient way to add a column to df1 named 'Sum' that will calculate the sum of name's data located in df2 between the Date1 and Date2 referred in df1 (excluding Date1 and including Date2).

Desired result should be:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                          'Date1':['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'], 
                          'Date2':['2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05'],
                          'Sum': [2+3, 8+9, 14+15]})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to use `apply` that filters based on your condition and sums up:

```
def temp_func(x, df2):
    col = str(x['Name'])
    return df2[(df2['Date'] <= x['Date2'] ) & (df2['Date'] > x['Date1'])][col].sum()
df1['Sum'] = df1.apply(lambda x: temp_func(x, df2), axis=1)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  Name                Date1                Date2  Sum
0    A  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-03 00:00:00    5
1    B  2023-01-02 00:00:00  2023-01-04 00:00:00   17
2    C  2023-01-03 00:00:00  2023-01-05 00:00:00   29
```

Comment: Thank you works well too! Both solutions (yours and Shubham Sharma) do the job. As mentioned above, not sure which one is actually faster at larger scale, I would need to try.

Answer (score 1):

##### Step by step solution

Melt the dataframe df2

```
df = df2.melt(id_vars=['Date'], var_name='Name')

#          Date Name  value
# 0  2023-01-01    A      1
# 1  2023-01-02    A      2
# 2  2023-01-03    A      3
# 3  2023-01-04    A      4
# 4  2023-01-05    A      5
# 5  2023-01-01    B      6
# 6  2023-01-02    B      7
# 7  2023-01-03    B      8
# 8  2023-01-04    B      9
# 9  2023-01-05    B     10
# 10 2023-01-01    C     11
# 11 2023-01-02    C     12
# 12 2023-01-03    C     13
# 13 2023-01-04    C     14
# 14 2023-01-05    C     15
```

Merge the melted dataframe with `df1`. Then mask the values where `Date` in df2 is out of the bounds

```
df = df1.merge(df, on='Name', how='left')
df['value'] = df['value'].where(df.eval('`Date1` <= `Date` <= `Date2`'))

#    Name                Date1                Date2       Date  value
# 0     A  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-03 00:00:00 2023-01-01    1.0
# 1     A  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-03 00:00:00 2023-01-02    2.0
# 2     A  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-03 00:00:00 2023-01-03    3.0
# 3     A  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-03 00:00:00 2023-01-04    NaN
# 4     A  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-03 00:00:00 2023-01-05    NaN
# 5     B  2023-01-02 00:00:00  2023-01-04 00:00:00 2023-01-01    NaN
# 6     B  2023-01-02 00:00:00  2023-01-04 00:00:00 2023-01-02    7.0
# 7     B  2023-01-02 00:00:00  2023-01-04 00:00:00 2023-01-03    8.0
# 8     B  2023-01-02 00:00:00  2023-01-04 00:00:00 2023-01-04    9.0
# 9     B  2023-01-02 00:00:00  2023-01-04 00:00:00 2023-01-05    NaN
# 10    C  2023-01-03 00:00:00  2023-01-05 00:00:00 2023-01-01    NaN
# 11    C  2023-01-03 00:00:00  2023-01-05 00:00:00 2023-01-02    NaN
# 12    C  2023-01-03 00:00:00  2023-01-05 00:00:00 2023-01-03   13.0
# 13    C  2023-01-03 00:00:00  2023-01-05 00:00:00 2023-01-04   14.0
# 14    C  2023-01-03 00:00:00  2023-01-05 00:00:00 2023-01-05   15.0
```

Group the dataframe and aggregate value with sum

```
df = df.groupby(list(df1.columns), as_index=False)['value'].sum()

#   Name      Date1      Date2  value
# 0    A 2023-01-01 2023-01-03    6.0
# 1    B 2023-01-02 2023-01-04   24.0
# 2    C 2023-01-03 2023-01-05   42.0
```

Comment: Thank you works well! Actually both solutions (yours and Suraj Shourie) do the job. Not sure which one is actually faster at larger scale, I would need to try.